# Neural Network regression when the output is imbalanced

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, artificial-intelligence, regression

I am trying to perform regression using a neural network to predict a single output from 146 input features.

I applied Standard Scaling on all inputs and output.

I monitor the Mean Absolute Error after training and it is unreasonably high on the train, validation and test sets (I am not even overfitting).

I suspect this is due to the fact that the output variable is very imbalanced (see histogram).
From the histogram it is possible to see that most of the samples are grouped around 0 but there is also another small group of samples around -5.

[Histogram of the imbalanced output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvRHP.png)

This is model creation code:

```
input = Input(batch_shape=(None, X.shape[1]))
layer1 = Dense(20, activation='relu')(input)
layer1 = Dropout(0.3)( layer1)
layer1 = BatchNormalization()(layer1)
layer2 = Dense(5, activation='relu',
               kernel_regularizer='l2')(layer1)
layer2 = Dropout(0.3)(layer2)
layer2 = BatchNormalization()(layer2)
out_layer = Dense(1, activation='linear')(layer2)
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=out_layer)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizers.adam() 
, metrics=['mae'])
```

This is the model summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 146)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 20)                2940      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 20)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 20)                80        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 5)                 105       
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 5)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 5)                 20        
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 6         
=================================================================
Total params: 3,151
Trainable params: 3,101
Non-trainable params: 50
_________________________________________________________________
```

Looking at the actual model predictions, the large error mainly happens for samples with a true output value around -5 (the small group of samples).

I tried many configurations for the hyperparameters but still the error is very high.

I see many suggestions on performing neural network classification on imbalanced data but what could be done with regression?
It seems odd to me that a regression neural network is not learning this correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please notice that he very notion of *imbalance* is *not defined* for regression settings. What you actually mean is that your output variable has a rather great *range*...

Comment: "I suspect this is due to the fact that the output variable is very imbalanced" Is there a reason you suspect this is the case? It may be the case that your features do not have enough predictive power. Or maybe, with 146 input features, a first layer with 20 neurons is too small. In my experience, the shape of the output is not a hindrance to learning, provided there is enough information in the features.

Comment: Thanks @michael, the reason I suspect this is because with the same 146 input variables I am also predicting 20 other output variables (with a separate model for each output). Most of them give me great results. Those that do not have a highly imbalanced output(or a not so great range as desertnaut pointed out). Is there some way that you recommend to check if the input features do indeed have predictive power over an output feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your histogram, it looks as though it's rare for there to be a non-zero output. This is similar to a classification problem where we're trying to predict a rare class, in that a strong strategy in terms of the loss function is simply to guess the most common class - in this case your modal value of zero.

You should do some research around what people do to predict rare events or to classify inputs when some classes are rare. E.g. this discussion might be helpful: https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/412wpp/predicting_rare_events_how_to_prevent_machine/

Some strategies you might try include

- Removing most of the zero-output training examples so that your training data is more balanced
- Creating or acquiring more non-zero training examples
- Using a different machine learning algorithm (someone at the link I provided recommends boosting. I wonder if you'd get good results from using a residual neural network structure, which is in some ways similar to boosting)
- Re-structuring or rescaling your data to add more weight to the rare values

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you have a normal distribution with a very small standard deviation.  In which case this should train just as well as any other probability distribution.